# Styled components arithmetic operations

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qbtqns?file=index.tsx)

Its a simple react app where I'm using Styled Components with a theme

The theme is like

```
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";

export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  sizes: {
    height: "50px",
    width: "50px"
  }
};
```

Is it possible to use the theme values with arithmetic operations in the styled component

So something like

```
height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height}+
    ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height};
```

This doesn't work in my demo but I didn't know if the syntax was incorrect or its just not possible.

Comment: `"50px" + "50px"` = "50px50px".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply this your theme should look this way, props will be numbers, instead of strings.

```
export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  sizes: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  }
};
```

So you can set your height now.

```
height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height + theme.sizes.height};
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case but I can't change the theme. Is there a way with the current theme

Comment: If you're absolutely sure it will always be a string with the "px" suffix, you could just trim the last two characters and cast the result to an integer. Buts pretty hacky.. I don't think I would actually recommend doing it. But its possible.

Comment: I did try this like `height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height.replace("px", "")}+
    ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height.replace("px", "")};`

Comment: Why are you doing it in two functions? I'm not familiar with styled components, but from a plain JS perspective that doesn't look right.. Put it in one function like the answer here did. You also missed the "cast the result to an integer" part. Even in a single function I would imagine this will result in "5050".